# Why does dask.distributed.Client raise "TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object" when provided with a used defined LocalCluster argument?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am able to create a `dask.distributed.LocalCluster` implicitly by using the empty argument constructor of `dask.distributed.Client`. However, when I attempt to explicitly define the cluster with a keyword argument, it fails and raises the exception: `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object`.

A simple reproducer is below:

```py
import dask.bag
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster


def main():
    with Client():
        dask.bag.from_sequence(range(5)).map(print).compute()  # prints 0 through 4

    cluster = LocalCluster()
    with Client(cluster=cluster):  # raises TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
        dask.bag.from_sequence(range(5)).map(print).compute()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have provided the wrong keyword argument to the `Client` constructor.
The `cluster` keyword arg that you provided gets interpreted as a keyword argument that should be passed to the workers. Since `LocalCluster` cannot be pickled this generates the exception that you see.

`Client(cluster=cluster)` should be replaced with `Client(address=cluster)` or simply `Client(cluster)`.

A complete working example then is:

```py
import dask.bag
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster


def main():
    cluster = LocalCluster()
    with Client(address=cluster):
        dask.bag.from_sequence(range(5)).map(print).compute()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```